# How to access the variable from other class with extend?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Hello I would like to ask how can I get the $manufacturer and $id from the function postData() which included with other class. So I can pass it to my model. Thank you.

```
class postDataManager{

   public function postData(){
       $manufacturer = $_POST['manufacturer'];
       $id = $_POST['id'];  
   }
}

class manufactureController extends postDataManager{

  private $model;

    public function __construct(){
       $this->model = new manufacturerModel();
       $postDataManager= new postDataManager();
    }

   public function addManufacturer(){ //get the add function
      //here i need access for the variable $manufaturer from class postData function
       $this->model->addProcess($manufacturer);     
   }

   public function updateManufacturer(){ //get the update function
      //here i need access for the variable $manufaturer and $id from class postData function
       $this->model->updateProcess($id, $manufacturer);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently those two variables are lost once the `postData()` method is left, since they belong to the *local scope* of the method. You need to define properties for them.

Take a look at this modified example:

```
<?php
class manufacturerModel {
}

class postDataManager {
  protected $id;
  protected $manufacturer;

  public function __construct($manufacturer, $id) {
    $this->manufacturer = $manufacturer;
    $this->id = $id;  
  }
}

class manufactureController extends postDataManager {
  private $model;

  public function __construct($manufacturer, $id) {
    parent::__construct($manufacturer, $id);
     $this->model = new manufacturerModel();
  }

  public function addManufacturer() { //get the add function
     $this->model->addProcess($this->manufacturer);     
  }

  public function updateManufacturer() { //get the update function
     $this->model->updateProcess($this->id, $this->manufacturer);
  }

  public function echoContent() {
    echo sprintf("manufacturer: %s\nid: %s\n", $this->manufacturer, $this->id);
  }  
}

// some example values
$_POST['manufacturer'] = "Manufactum Ltd.";
$_POST['id'] = 17397394;

$controller = new manufactureController($_POST['manufacturer'], $_POST['id']);
$controller->echoContent();
```

Now those values are stored in a persistent manner inside the object. Since your second class extends the first class those properties are also part of objects instantiate from that derived class, so you can access them likewise using the `$this` reference, unless they have been declared `private` in that class.

The output of above demo code is:

```
manufacturer: Manufactum Ltd.
id: 17397394
```

These are the basics of OOP (object oriented programming), this is explained in every tutorial.

Comment: Sorry I'm just starting to learn OOP. how can I call them to my model.. Like now I have in model public function addProcess($manufacturer){  }

Comment: I tried to echo the user input. It doesnt echoing the user input @arkascha

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten I am sorry, I had to revise the code to make it work. Been a while for me to program php. ;-)

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten About that manufacturerModel: you have multiple options, there is no definite answer, since things depend on what you want to implement. You can call those methods in an explicit manner like you support now. Or you can hand over those values to the class constructor just as I demonstrated when instantiating the object of class `manufactureController`.

Comment: got an error .. Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in line 11 .. and also here $controller = new manufactureController($_POST['manufacturer'], $_POST['id']);

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten Works for me. Sure you have tried the current version?

Comment: yes I tried your edited code.. Notice: Undefined index: manufacturer ,Notice: Undefined index: id line 49 which $controller = new manufactureController($_POST['manufacturer'], $_POST['id']);

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in line 11 which is $this->$manufacturer = $manufacturer;

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten Sorry, but that is _not_ the code I posted. In the code above I defined those two values right in the lines above for testing purpose. I cannot tell you why they are not defined for you, but certainly you do _not_ use the code above.

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten Also I definitely do _not_ have `$this->$manufacturer` in my code, it should be `$this->manufacturer`. Please do not claim that you are using the exact code if obviously you don't.

Comment: now its working.. but i have error on the Notice: Undefined index: manufacturer and id which $controller = new manufactureController($_POST['manufacturer'], $_POST['id']);

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten I answered to that 4 comments above.

Answer (score 0):

create property with name of $manufacturer and $id

```
class postDataManager{
   protected $manufacturer;
   protected $id;
   public function postData($manufacturer){
       $this->manufacturer = $_POST['manufacturer'];
       $this->id = $_POST['id'];  
   }
}
```

Now you can access with in child Class

Comment: I tried to echo the manufacturer. It doenst displaying the user input

Comment: `$manufacturer` and `$id` are _not_ objects here, but properties. Please do not confuse people by mixing terms.

Comment: sorry my bad, I've typed mistakenly

Comment: You should call postData function, or rename it to __construct

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `$manufacturer` and `$id` variables in postDataManager class and in postData function then use `$this->manufacturer=$_POST['manufacturer'];` and `$this->id=$_POST['id'];`